# Show query on search results page in SP2010

Tags: search

I setup a web parts page in SP2010 with an advanced search web part on it. When the advanced search form is submitted, it sends its parameters to a custom page named results.aspx, where I have web parts to display the search results and other search-related data. That's all working fine.

What I can't get working is showing the user their query on the results page. Ideally I'd like to redisplay the advanced search web part with their search parameters filled in. When I put the advanced search web part on the page, however, it comes up with all the fields empty. Is there a way to auto-populate this web part with the search parameters on the results page? If not, is there any other way to show the user what they searched for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you posted your query to another page, the query should be in Response.QueryString right? You should be able to fetch it from there

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I sometimes forget that SharePoint is also an ASP app :P